# Must have software for IT architects

Tags: untagged

What are the tools that every professional IT architect must have?

The definition of "IT architect" that I am referring to, is the one for individuals who make the recommendations for software/hardware infrastructure (enterprise systems at a high level)
A Person that is a Technology/Project advisor who understands system design, security, system extensibility/scalability and interoperability, costs and operational considerations.

Answer (score 6):

The one tool I can't live without is Visio (combined with a million downloaded system-specific shapes from visiocafe.com).

Comment: Visio cafe is the best :)

Answer (score 5):

Paper and pencil. Nothing beats that :)

Answer (score 2):

The term architect has many differing connotations that make this question a bit hazy, but in general:

1. Good design software - for prototyping, blueprints, and presentations
2. Good utility executables for machine monitoring, diagnostics, file transfer, benchmarking, security assessment, backup
3. Boot-level versions of #2
4. Good Remote Access software
5. Good telecommunications software - Video/Voice conferencing, IM Chat, Web Meetings
6. Configuration Management Software
7. Kiddie Scripts

(kidding on that last one)

Comment: kiddy scripts are handy: but only for doing basic self-penetration testing. If kiddy scripts can't get in, then somebody else using those same scripts will be just going nowhere.

Answer (score 1):

Whiteboard. When one is lacking, you're likely to start writing on the walls (or wishing that you could).